# Extracting the second last date from a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to apply a formula that will extract the second last date of a string. Below example of strings:

```
DA1234621222 Corp|0|3|;2;1;3;8;01/01/2024;2;20000.00;2;2;1000000.00;|15|11/30/2023|
US12356HNM19 Corp|0|3|;2;4;3;1;04/29/2024;2;21000.000;2;.000;5;10/29/2024;2;21000.000;2;.000;5;04/29/2025;2;21000.000;2;.000;5;10/29/2025;2;2100.000;2;1000000.00;|15|10/31/2023|
```

In the first string, the second last date is 01/01/2024 and for the second string it is 10/29/2025.
Hope someone can advise, thanks in advance.

I tried to use `Find` function but was unable to come up with a formula with locate the second last date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"|",";"}),CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(t,ISNUMBER(FIND("/",t))),-2))`

First we declare `t` the textsplit of `A1` by delimiters `|` and `;`.

`t` is filtered for only values containing `/` and CHOOSECOLS takes the second last string. (If you add `--` in front of CHOOSECOLS it will be converted from the string to an actual value, which you could format as a date)

If a non-date string could potentially consist a `/` you could use `=LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"|",";"}),CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(t,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("??/??/????",t))),-2))`

Comment: That is the approach I would take

Comment: Not posting any of it as an **answer**, it would become a **duplicate/plagiarized content**, but you can make it short: `=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(A1,,{"|",";"}),@TAKE(FILTER(x,1-ISERR(FIND("/",x))),-2)/1)` or `=LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"|",";"}),@TAKE(FILTER(t,1-ISERR(SEARCH("/??/",t))),,-2)+0)`

Comment: Nice and compact

Comment: Thank you so much P.b and Mayukh! The formulas worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Vba Code

```
 Function LastDate(rng As Range, Optional Number=1)
    Dim lenstring, s As Integer
    lenstring = Len(rng)
    
    s = 0
    For i = lenstring To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(rng, i, 1) = "/" Then
            s = s + 1
            If s = Number * 2 Then
                LastDate = Mid(rng, i - 2, 10)
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Use

```
=LastDate(A1,2)
```

Comment: Second last was the question.

Comment: My English is not very good. Edit my post.

Comment: Much better and can be used in older Excel as well.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I think if you use Split function with delimiters semi-colon[;] and pipe[|], your task can be easier.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2010 for a formula, you may try this:

First create a named formula named `seq` which will generate an array of numbers from `1` to `255`

`Formulas=>Define Name`

```
=ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,255))
```

[image]

Then use this formula in `A1`, for example, and fill down

```
=INDEX(DATEVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",";"),";",REPT(" ",99)),IF(seq=1,1,seq*99),99))), AGGREGATE(14,6,ISNUMBER(DATEVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",";"),";",REPT(" ",99)),IF(seq=1,1,seq*99),99))))*seq,2))
```

or formatted differently:

```
=INDEX(
    DATEVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "|", ";"), ";", REPT(" ", 99)), IF(seq = 1, 1, seq * 99), 99))),
    AGGREGATE(
        14,
        6,
        ISNUMBER(DATEVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "|", ";"), ";", REPT(" ", 99)), IF(seq = 1, 1, seq * 99), 99)))) *
            seq,
        2
    )
)
```

***Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Be sure to format the result as a ***Date***. Otherwise you may see a 5 digit number.

***Algorithm***

- Replace each delimiter with 99 spaces
- Create an array of values using the `MID` function with a start number of `1,99,198...`

  - Trim each entry in the array
- The `DATEVALUE` function should convert each element that looks like a date into a date, otherwise it should return an error
- `ISNUMBER` will then convert this into an array of row numbers or zero's to find the index into the array for the actual dates
- `AGGREGATE` will return the penultimate element index that contains a date
- `INDEX` into the array using the index to return the penultimate date

Answer (score 0):

> I got the answer without spill array, you just need to drag the
> formula.

[image: Result]

```
=MID(C3,CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FIND("/",C3,SEQUENCE(,LEN(C3))),""),1),1,3)-2,10)
```

> I have taken 1st & 2nd dates in my formula, If you need only 2nd date,
> try this one.

```
=MID(C3,CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FIND("/",C3,SEQUENCE(,LEN(C3))),""),1),3)-2,10)
```

[image: Result2]